# combining 2 strings in another string alphabetically

Tags: c, string, pointers, recursion

I want to write a recursive function that combines 2 string into one string that is in alphabetic order , the 2 strings are only small letters and in ascending alphabetical order . Example :
s1: "aegiz"  s2: "abhxy"  s3: "aabeghixyz"

I am still new to recursive functions and to C in general and I think that this can be solved in a better way than what I did...

my code so far:

```html
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 50
char *combinealph(char *str1, char *str2, char *str3);
void main()
{
 char *str1[N], *str2[N],*str3;
 int length;
 printf("Enter first string:\n");
 gets(str1);
 printf("Enter second string:\n");
 flushall(1);
 gets(str2);
 length = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2);
 str3 = (char*)malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char));
 printf("The combined string :\n");
 puts(combinealph(str1, str2, str3));
 getch();
}

char *combinealph(char *str1, char *str2, char *str3)
{
 if (*str1 == '\0' && *str2 != '\0')
  strcpy(str3, str2);
  return str3;
 if (*str1 != '\0' && *str2 == '\0')
  strcpy(str3, str1);
  return str3;
 if (*str1 == '\0' && *str2 == '\0')
   return '\0';

 if (*str1 >= *str2)
 {
  strcpy(str3, str1);
  return strcat(*str3, combinealph(str1 + 1, str2, str3+1));
 }
 if (*str1 < *str2)
 {
  *str3 = *str2; 
  return strcat(*str3, combinealph(str1, str2 + 1, str3+1));
 }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Questions about improving code belong on Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: well my code doesn't  work so i guess how can i make it work is the question ?

Comment: Make the function `void` and get rid of all the `return`s. Get rid of the `strcat`s, too. And you have `strcpy(str3, str1);` where you mean `*str3 = *str1;` (5th line from the bottom).. BTW, the operation you're performing is called a "merge".

Comment: ...by asking a better question. *"I think that this can be solved in a better way than what I did"* implies your code does work, and you have not said what, if anything, is wrong with it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @n4tri0s Why does the result string contain two letters 'a' and only one letter 'z'?

Comment: @ooga If I got rid of return's how can I make it recursive then ??

Comment: @VladfromMoscow My code doesn't work and the example is from the exercise that I want to solve .

Comment: @VladfromMoscow because the source strings contain two letter `a` and one letter `z`.

Comment: It's recursive because it calls itself, not because it returns anything in particular. The returns are useless since the result is being passed back in the 3rd parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * combine_strings( char *result, const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    if ( *s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0' )
    {
        *result = '\0';
        return result;
    }
    else if ( *s1 == '\0' )
    {
        *result++ = *s2++;
        return combine_strings( result, s1, s2 ) - 1;
    }
    else if ( *s2 == '\0' )
    {
        *result++ = *s1++;
        return combine_strings( result, s1, s2 ) - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        *result++ = *s2 < *s1 ? *s2++ : *s1++;
        return combine_strings( result, s1, s2 ) - 1;
    }        
}    

int main(void)
{
    const char *s1 = "aegiz"; 
    const char *s2 = "abhxy";
    char result[ strlen( s1 ) + strlen( s2 ) + 1];

    printf( "%s\n", combine_strings( result, s1, s2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
aabeghixyz
```

You can make the function shorter. For example

```
char * combine_strings( char *result, const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    if ( *s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0' )
    {
        *result = '\0';
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        *result++ = ( *s2 && *s2 < *s1 ) || !*s1 ? *s2++ : *s1++;
        return combine_strings( result, s1, s2 ) - 1;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thank you , this is exactly what I want.
one question : can you please explain the purpose of the -1 at the end of return ?

Comment: @n4tri0s  The function should return pointer to the first character of the result string that it could be used in output functions as it is shown in my demonstrative program, because within the function the original pointer is increased.

Comment: yes much shorter but for me I had to look at it for 10 minutes until I understood what it does :) Thank you again

Comment: @n4tri0s Sometimes even very qualified programmers look at an evident code and can not find a bug.:)